# Keep the screen open

Tags: c++, if-statement, exit

In my C++ book examples I have used system ("pause") to keep screen open which I learned from OS for homework only. Now I have an example from my book that uses exit() and depending on true or false my screen disappears. If I take out exit() the program keeps calculating (which is why author put in exit()) but how to resolve this issue? I am using Microsoft VS C++Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

```
//prime.cpp
// demonstrates IF statement with prime numbers
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <process.h>        //for exit()

int main()
    {
        unsigned long n,j;
        cout << "Enter a number:  ";
        cin >>n;                    //get number to test
        for (j=2; j<= n/2; j++)     //divide by integer from
            if(n%j==0)              //2 on up; if remainder is 0,
            {                       //it's divisible by j

            cout <<"It's not prime; divisible by " <<j<<endl;
            exit (0);               //exit from program
            }
        cout <<"It's prime\n";

        system ("pause");    //the only way I can get screen to stay open
        return 0;
    }
```

If answer is prime number works fine. If answer is a non prime screen winks out. If I remove exit() I get this result:

Enter a number: 8
It’s not prime; divisible by 2
It’s not prime; divisible by 4
It’s prime
Press any key to continue. . .

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run a terminal program, run it from a terminal. The screen is disappearing because of the way you are invoking the program. There's nothing wrong with the program.

Comment: I agree program is fine. However up until now I have done book exercises and kept screen open, but with new code: exit() it closes when IF statement is true. As a noob I am not sure what you mean by “run it from a terminal”, but I am learning a lot by trying to understand the responses as they are presented-thanks!

Comment: @AbigailShearer: You are writing terminal programs, not GUI programs. But you are running them from a GUI, not a terminal. So something is creating a temporary terminal for the program to run from. If you actually ran them from a terminal, they would use the existing terminal, and there would be no new screen to disappear. You can get a terminal in Windows by typing "cmd" in the run bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by restructuring your code to use `break;` in place of `exit(0)`. The former will only jump out of the loop, while the latter will end the entire program.

When the call to `exit(0)` occurs, execution never reaches your `system("pause");` call, so the program ends immediately without prompting the user to continue.

`break;`, on the other hand, will just jump out of the loop.

If you need more guidance on how to implement this specifically, let me know. Since it's homework you should give it a try individually first :). Hint: Just using `break;` in place of `exit(0)` won't work, because of how your code is set up.

Comment: Thanks-BTW I say it is "homework" but I am teaching myself! So, I already tried break and yes it stops calculating but as you imply does not do the whole trick as it also includes the "It's prime" as well after "It's not Prime; divisible by 2". I tried moving curly brackets too and also removed them and put an ELSE for the "It's Prime". Thanks again for assistance!

Comment: @AbigailShearer: Ah, ok :). Glad it helped. You could also maintain a bool flag variable outside of the loop to indicate if a factor was found.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move out of the loop at any point, you can use the **break** statement. and for the screen pause, you may use the **getch()** function in **conio.h** , but its not the **Standard C++** . **getch()** waits for a character input (you may use it with this statement, Press any key to continue). For getch(), use the ISO C++ conformant **_getch()**